# Add body class based on JS Object variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JS object as shown below with a few viariables - I use this to push some data into elements on my site - I wonder if its possible to add a class to the body with the same name as the data in the `company` variable? So if the data in that variable would say "apple computers" would it be possible to add "applecomputers" or "apple" and "computers" as a body class?

```
var retailerData = {
    "del": {
        "zip": "",
        "city": ""
    },
    "user": {
        "country": "",
        "phone": "0",
        "nbrOrders": ,
        "isPunchOut": false,
        "name": "",
        "company": "name name name",
        "salesPerson": "",
        "customerNo": "",
        "email": "d"
    },
    "order": {
        "shippingSum": 0.0,
        "shippingFormatSum": "0:-",
        "orderno": "0",
        "orderFormatSum": "595:-",
        "formatQty": "1 ",
        "voucher": "",
        "orderFormatVat": "148,75:-",
        "currencySymbol": ":-",
        "currency": "SEK",
        "orderVat": 148.75,
        "orderSum": 595.0,
        "items": [{
            "imageURI": "\/imgr\/84c2bfee-ff5b-462c-89d3-dc73b338c890\/70\/70",
            "qtyAvail": 0,
            "price": 595.0,
            "qty": 1,
            "artno": "U4414E",
            "vat": 148.75,
            "formatVat": "148,75:-",
            "id": "20730",
            "label": "",
            "category": "",
            "formatPrice": "595:-",
            "manufacturer": "HP"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as

```
var company = retailerData.user.company;
company.split( " " ).forEach( function( item ){
    $( "body" ).addClass( item );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plain old vanilla JavaScript. The following should work.

```
document.body.className += " " + retailerData.user.company;
```

The space is required to ensure that it is a new class and not changing an existing one.

Alternatively, the more modern approach below (Not supported below IE10) is more flexible.

```
document.body.classList.add(retailerData.user.company);
```

You could also combine this with a bit of string manipulation to change "apple computers" into "applecomputers" as you stated.

```
retailerData.user.company.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. class name will be 'namenamename'

   ```
   var companyClass = retailerData.user.company.replace(" ", "");

   $("body" ).addClass( companyClass );
   ```
2. class name will be 'name-name-name'

   ```
   var companyClass = retailerData.user.company.replace(" ", "-");

   $("body" ).addClass( companyClass );
   ```